# bug in the implementation of multithreading

Tags: multithreading, api, lua

Please help me to find a bug in the implementation of multithreading.

I'm trying to implement multithreading through a hook, which after n number of iterations sends to the stack lua_yield(L, 0);, which suspends the main thread, yielding control to the second thread. 
The foo function is run from the main thread loop of the main function once, which is a loop when the yield () function is called in the foo function, it yields control to the main thread(main function), then turn on the hook suspends the main thread(main function) after n time, yielding control to the second thread(foo function). All goes well until the 150th iteration of the main thread. Help to understand where is the error?

```
static int timerfirsttread = 0;// таймер для первого потока.
void LUAHook(lua_State* L, lua_Debug* ar) {
  timerfirsttread++; 
  if (timerfirsttread > 8) {
    timerfirsttread = 0;
    lua_yield(L, 0);
  }
};
int my_yield(lua_State* L) {
  int args = lua_gettop(L);args++;
  lua_State* L1 = lua_newthread(L); 
  lua_pushthread(L1);
  return lua_yield(L, args);/* Когда функция C вызывает lua_yield таким 
  образом, запущенная сопрограмма приостанавливает
  свое выполнение, и вызов lua_resume этой запущенной процедуры 
  возвращается.*/
};
int yield(lua_State* L) {return lua_yield(L, 0);/* Параметр res - это 
  число значений из стека,
  которые передаются как результаты lua_resume.*/
};
const char* LUA = R"(
  function foo(x) x = x or 3
    print(" func foo "..x.. " \n")
    for i = 1, x do 
      print(" func foo "..i.."\n")
      yield()
    end
  end
  function main()
    for i = 1, 3220000 do
      z=i*6
      print(" func main "..i.."\n")
      if i ==1
      then my_yield(foo,10000036) 
      end
    end end
    )"; 
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();/*Функция создает новое Lua состояние. 
    Она вызывает lua_newstate с функцией-*/
    luaL_openlibs(L); lua_State* L1 = NULL;
    lua_register(L, "my_yield", my_yield);
    lua_register(L, "yield", yield); 
    cout << "\n"; checkerror(L, LUA);
    lua_getglobal(L, "main"); 
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0); /* Запускает и продолжает сопрограмму в данном 
    потоке L. */
    L1 = lua_tothread(L, -1); lua_pop(L, 1); lua_xmove(L, L1, 
      lua_gettop(L));lua_remove(L1, 1);
    int args = lua_gettop(L1);// cout << args << endl;// Аргументы.
    for (int i = 1; i > args; i++) {lua_pushvalue(L1, i);}
    args--; lua_resume(L1, L, args); lua_xmove(L, L1, 1); //showstack(L1);
    while ( LUA_OK != lua_status(L)) { // пока поток main не завершен. 
      if (LUA_YIELD == lua_status(L1)) {// если поток 2 на паузе.
        lua_sethook(L, LUAHook, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 6);//Пауза после 6 итерации. 
        lua_resume(L, L1, 0); 
        }// main
      if (LUA_YIELD == lua_status(L)){// если поток main на паузе.
        lua_sethook(L, LUAHook, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 0);// отключить хук. 
        lua_resume(L1, L, 0);// foo
      }
      if (LUA_OK == lua_status(L1)) {// если поток foo завершен. 
        lua_sethook(L, LUAHook, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 0);// отключить хук. 
        lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
      }
      if (LUA_OK == lua_status(L)) { break; }// если поток main завершен. 
    };
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
  };
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in the paste? The source is pretty hard to read like this

Comment: thank you You for attention to topic, already a long time not can find answer on my question.